# Override .NET Generic List<MyType>.Contains(MyTypeInstance)?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Is it possible, and if so how do I override the `Contains` method of an otherwise normal `List<T>`, where `T` is my own, custom type?

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your question what you need to achieve. Do you a) need the standard Contains to work with your custom type or b) do some special logic when Contains is called?

Comment: Peter, basically the List<T> I'm having is not in-memory at runtime, it's loosely/weak-referenced to an OODBMS. If I do a native .net .Contains on the List it retrieves the whole list from the oodbms backend and evaluates locally. Therefore I wanted to override it with proper (backend)query syntax..

Comment: @Jörg - so with that in mind, how does overriding Equals/GetHashCode solve your problem (@Cans answer)?

Comment: It didn't... prematurely gave out the 'solved'... What I finally/basically did was write an extension method for List<MyType> that internally uses the oodbms query syntax to check for existence.

Comment: The oodbms is interface-changes sensitive and requires a migration path when a new one was added & I didn't really require that at this point. However, your answer -was- the one that give me that little push in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your own Contains implementation you could create a class that implements the IList interface. That way your class will look like a IList. You could have a real List internally to do the standard stuff.

```
class MyTypeList : IList<MyType>
{
    private List<MyType> internalList = new ...;

    public bool Contains(MyType instance)
    {

    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to do comparisons; this checks first to see if your object implements `IEquatable<T>`; otherwise is uses `object.Equals`.

So; the easiest thing to do is to override `Equals` (always update `GetHashCode` to match the logic in `Equals`). Alternatively, use LINQ instead:

```
bool hasValue = list.Any(x => x.Foo == someValue);
```

Comment: @Marc Gravell: so if I want to test the 'equality' of 2 custom classes that only contain properties and fields, I need to implement IEquatable in my class? I must have been really tired when I made the assumption that 2 classes would be considered 'equal' just because the fields contained the same values in each class. :/ ...thanks for the tip   ;)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: well, technically, it wouldn't matter what they contain. What is important is that I 'properly' implement IEquatable<MyClass> and select the field that should dictate whether another MyClass is considered equal.

Comment: @dboarman - exactly. And re your first point, IIRC structs *do* behave like that, so you weren't a million miles off.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class (`MyType`).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what specific needs you have in your override you might use Linq expression for doing that:

```
list.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("asdas", .....)) // whatever comparison you need
```

You can then wrap it in an extension method for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the equals of you custom type, the contains function of List will work

Comment: No, List<T> will never use the == operator; only Equals

Comment: Don't think it deserved a downvote, though. The Equals is true; fixed that (+1)